# How to create a message-box in Windows 10 with the same style as shutdown message-box

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, messaging

I'm writing a .bat file and I want to create a message box with the style used when displaying shutdown messages, such as the screenshot below (obviously without saying "your'e about to signed out but with a different message):

[image]

I've tried the `msg * my message` command, but this one displays the message in the classic message box:

[image]

Is it possible to display a message box with the new style from a .bat file?

Comment: This may be can done with a custom HTA file !

Comment: @Hackoo possible hybrid/HTA+CMD?